# Cannot convert string to int using ArcPy Calculate Field?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

When I load a csv file to join with ArcPy, it converts all string fields that are numeric to integers. Therefore, I have to add another field within the feature class that I'm using for joining that is an integer version of the one I originally intended to use.

There are two approaches I've tried to convert the contents of the original field to an int:

Approach 1:

```
arcpy.AddField_management(layerName, "BG10_INT", "LONG", 12, "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "")
expression = "toInt(!BG10!)"
codeblock = """def toInt(value):
    if value.isdigit():
        return int(value)
    else:
        return 0"""
arcpy.CalculateField_management (layerName, "BG10_INT", expression, "PYTHON", codeblock)
```

Approach 2:

```
for row in rows:
    if row.BG10.isdigit():
        row.BG10_INT = int(row.BG10)
    else:
        row.BG10_INT = 0
    rows.updateRow(row)
```

With either approach, I get `The value type is incompatible with the field type. [BG10_INT]`. How could something so simple as converting string to int be such a challenge?

---

After several comments and an answer suggesting I define the `schema.ini` file for the csv file instead of the above conversions, I tried the following approach:

Approach 3

```
env.workspace = "C:/data/PCA"
f = open("C:/data/PCA/schema.ini", "wb")
text = ["[bg_to_tr.csv]", "ColNameHeader=True", "Format=CSVDelimited", "Col1=BG10 Text Width 12", "Col2=PrefBUC1 Text Width 10"]
for row in text:
    f.writerow(row)

f.close()

env.qualifiedFieldNames = False
inFeatures = "C:/geodatabases/Intermediate.gdb/BG_sample"
layerName = "BG_sample_lyr"
joinTable = "bg_to_tr.csv"
joinField = "BG10"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (inFeatures,  layerName)
outFeature = "C:/geodatabases/Intermediate.gdb/BG_sample_w_tr"
arcpy.AddJoin_management(layerName, joinField, joinTable, joinField)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layerName, outFeature)
```

This approach only works when I join manually (sans ArcPy) within ArcMap. However, for my purpose, this needs to be done with ArcPy. Is there an explanation why this only seems to work with ArcMap? The csv file was joined without adding it directly into the ArcMap TOC.

---

Here is a sample of the contents of the csv file:

```
"BG10","PrefBUC1"
"170312106022","0002804408"
"170312106023","0002804408"
"170312105012","0002804408"
```

If I open the csv file in ArcMap, it recognizes `schema.ini` and indicates the BG10 column as a String of length 12. When I look at the join output in `BG_sample_w_tr`, however, it indicates that it read it as data type Double.

If it matters, neither table contains null values for the joined fields.

Comment: Why not just set up a schema.ini file for the initial CSV import so it imports the data from the CSV to the correct field type from the beginning (details at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000010000000 near the bottom of the page)

Comment: Your first approach worked fine on my end. What is the field type for your `BG10` field?

Comment: I think you may mean CalculateField in your title, not Field Calculator.

Comment: @EmilBrundage - string of length 12

Comment: I haven't tested this, but if you add a dummy row to your original csv that only has text values for each field, the import may map all the fields to text for you.

Comment: Does it fail right away or only after a number of iterations? That would be interesting to know. It might be just one value causing the trouble. You could add a print statement to your loop, so whenever it crashes you would just have to check out your last printed value and then check in your table what is coming next. Could just be a typo resulting in a value that cannot be converted to a string.

Comment: @BritishSteel - it fails right away. I set up the conditional statements in my two approaches for that very reason.

Comment: Hm, could you maybe post a part of your csv? Or a screenshot?

Comment: @BritishSteel - see update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with the use of `dbfpy`. I converted my Python list to a dbf using this module, and joined the resulting table to the feature layer.

```
db = dbf.Dbf("C:/data/test.dbf", new=True)
db.addField(
("BG10", "C", 12),
("TR", "C", 10),
)

for i in l:
    rec = db.newRecord()
    rec["BG10"] = str(i[0])
    rec["TR"] = str(i[1])
    rec.store()

try:
    db.close()
except AttributeError:
    pass

inFeatures = "C:/data/Intermediate.gdb/BG_sample"
layerName = "BG_sample_lyr"
joinTable = "C:/data/test.dbf"
joinField = "BG10"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (inFeatures,  layerName)
outFeature = "C:/geodatabases/Intermediate.gdb/BG_sample_w_tr"
arcpy.AddJoin_management(layerName, joinField, joinTable, joinField)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layerName, outFeature)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can take care of this before ever trying to load the data into ArcGIS by creating a [`schema.ini` file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx). Simply use a text editor to save a file called `schema.ini` (no other extension) in the same folder as your CSV. Then, explicitly specify the data types for columns that you don't want ArcGIS to infer.

For example, if your CSV were called `mydata.csv` and the 4th column were the one ArcGIS is loading as text, your `schema.ini` would look like this:

```
[mydata.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=CSVDelimited
Col4=BG10 Long
```

ArcGIS always checks `schema.ini` files, and will therefore always correctly load the column as an integer if that is how you've specified it. If multiple CSV files are present in the same folder, they can all be controlled from the same `schema.ini`.

Comment: see edit. Joining after creating a `schema.ini` file only seems to work when manually joining within ArcMap, but not by using ArcPy.

Comment: Are there any rows where the "BG10" value is not an integer (even nulls)? How exactly are the "BG10" values encoded in the CSV, if you open it in a text editor?

Comment: neither table contains null values for the joined fields. The contents of the BG10 field are all string.

Comment: Try creating a Table View of your CSV with [`arcpy.MakeTableView_management()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006v000000), and then joining the Table View to the Feature Layer instead of the raw CSV.

Comment: That didn't work either. I know this deserves a separate question, but the data I'm joining was in a Python list form prior to writing to a csv. If I could simply join the Python list to the feature layer, that would be most preferable. I know this could be done with `UpdateCursor`, but that would be a nested loop - not the fastest way to do things. Otherwise an alternate option is converting the list into a dbf instead of a csv. I'll tinker with this when I get back to the office.